# My nd array is bbeing converted to a float when passsed

Tags: python, numpy, types

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as M
import pandas as pd
xread =(pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx')).to_numpy()
yread =(pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')).to_numpy()

x1 = xread
```

this is where i make the variablex1 as a 17378,12 array

```
def graddes(x1,x2,yread,w1,w2,b,a,iter,costfunc,compgrad):
    J_history = []
    p_history = []
    b = b
    w1= w1
    w2=w2

    for i in range(iter):
        dw1,dw2,db = compgrad(w1,w2,b,x1,x2,yread)
        w1 = w1-a*dw1
        w2 = w2-a*dw2
        b = b-a*db
        if i<100000:      # prevent resource exhaustion 
            J_history.append( costfunc(x1,x2, yread, w1,w2 , b))
            p_history.append([w,b])
        # Print cost every at intervals 10 times or as many iterations if < 10
        if i% M.ceil(iter/10) == 0:
            print(f"Iteration {i:4}: Cost {J_history[-1]:0.2e} ",
                  f"dj_dw1: {dw1: 0.3e},dj_dw2:{dw2:0.3e} dj_db: {db: 0.3e}  ",
                  f"w1: {w1: 0.3e},w2:{w2:0.3e} b:{b: 0.5e}")
    return(w1,w2,b,J_history)
```

it is called in tis function and still is an array
however wehn costfunc is called it becomes a float

```
def costfunc(w1,w2,b,yread,x1,x2):
    k=0
    for i in range(len(yread)):
        k = k+((np.dot(w1,x1[i])+np.dot(w2,x2[i])+b)-yread[i])**2
    err = k/(2*len(yread))
    return (err)
```

and i get this error

```
    k = k+((np.dot(w1,(x1[i,i]))+np.dot(w2,(x2[i]))+b)-yread[i])**2
                       ~~^^^^^
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

i tried at some forums but i couldnt find a reason why this is happening

Comment: Where are you calling it?

Comment: Site note: using `iter` as a parameter name is bad practice, since it shadows the builtin `iter`

Comment: Looking at the definition of `constfunc`, and comparing it to the call site, that call doesn't look like it's passing arguments in the right order.

Comment: We don't know what `a` is. Nor do we know what `dw?` are (what is returning `compgrad`). If you want some accurate help, post a [mre]. But the important point is that what is called `x1` in `costfunc` is what is called `w2` in `graddes`. And that `w2` is whatever is passed to `graddes` (we don't know it neither) transformed by `w2=w2-a*dw2`. `x1` initial value has nothing to do with it. So, as hpaulj said, you need to figure out why `w2` and/or `w2-a*dw2` is float.

Answer (score 0):

This reproduces your error:

```
x=np.arange(3); x1 = x[0]
type(x)
Out[14]: numpy.ndarray
type(x1)
Out[15]: numpy.int32
```

trying to index the selected item:

```
x1[1,2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 1
----> 1 x1[1,2]

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

You need to figure out why your `x1` is a scalar variable instead of a 2d array.